# What US state was this purchase made in?

Tags: united-states, commerce, online

I wish to file a claim in a class action settlement in the US. However, eligibility is dependent on what state you made a purchase "in" (the purchase being an item from an internet app).

If I am a legal resident of state A (and was physically in state A when I made the purchase), but the credit card I used to make the purchase has a billing address in state B, what state was the purchase made in? The company who runs the app is located in a third state, C.

I know billing addresses are used by businesses to determine who they may sell state-restricted goods to. Does the billing address have the same weight here?

Edit: The purchase was a subscription, no physical goods were shipped anywhere.

Comment: Was it a physical good? Where was it delivered to?

Comment: Where was the good shipped?

Comment: Isn't this a question for the lawyers handling the class action?